# IBM WebSphere enable PMI through wsadmin

Tags: websphere

I have to enable parameters for these objects :
For PMI-> JVM Name -> Custom

For the JDBC Connection Pools PMI module, click JDBC Connection Pools,
select the following metrics, and click Enable at the top of the table:
AllocateCount
CloseCount
ConnectionHandleCount
CreateCount
FaultCount
FreePoolSize
JDBCTime
ManagedConnectionCount
PercentMaxed
PercentUsed
PoolSize
PrepStmtCacheDiscardCount
ReturnCount
UseTime
WaitTime
WaitingThreadCount

click Servlet Session Manage,
select the following metrics, and click Enable at the top of the table:
ActivateNonExistSessionCount
ActiveCount
AffinityBreakCount
CacheDiscardCount
CreateCount
ExternalReadSize
ExternalReadTime
ExternalWriteSize
ExternalWriteTime
InvalidateCount
LifeTime
LiveCount
NoRoomForNewSessionCount
SessionObjectSize
TimeSinceLastActivated
TimeoutInvalidationCount

for more than 60 JVM's i have set these. Can someone help me out how to use wsadmin commands for this.

Answer (score 0):

General procedures regarding the use of wsadmin commands and PMI are documented in topic "Configuring the Performance Monitoring Infrastructure using scripting" at the IBM Knowledge Center for WebSphere Application Server: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_pmi.html.